Alt + Tab pane becomes opaque after snap windows
Like the title, the Alt + Tab window originally had a blurry translucency effect, but after snap windows, it disappeared and required a restart of explorer to recover.
This also affects the window suggestions module (i.e. all open windows are displayed on the other side, which can be clicked to fill the other side of the screen) that appears when snapping to a window. There is no such issue when using it for the first time
This issue only occurs under the current user, does not affect new users
(I'm oCd)
The black and white solid color is the occluded part
Img Before
Img After

edit your question to add some screenshots of before and after snap windows
